# Error in manifest - All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am getting "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.1, 25.3.1. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1` and `com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1`" error in Android manifest.

Earlier I used a version like " compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27+'" then i modified as per suggestion from android studio. But still I am getting the same error. Please help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: `com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.0`

Comment: `com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0`

Comment: I didnt use those 2 in my manifest

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project

Comment: try to match the library with same version you are using

Answer (score 1):

One of your third-party libraries may using support library version  25.3.1. 
Try changing your support library version to  25.3.1 and sync your project.